# In Scala Reflection, is the compile time universe accessible?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

In this document:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html

Scala reflection universe is described to have 2 implementations: 1 for runtime (under scala.reflect.runtime) and 1 for compile time (under scala.reflect.macro).

However, I can only access the runtime universe by:

```
scala.reflect.runtime.universe
```

The compile time universe package has no concrete implementation under it.  Is the implementation and ability to call it deliberately hidden, with implementation hardcoded by scala compiler? If that's the case, whats the reason to mandate specifying a universe before using Scala reflection?

Thanks a lot for any insight.

Comment: You can access some compile-time universe in a macro implementation by importing it from the context, e.g. `def macroImpl(c: whitebox.Context)(arg: c.Tree) = { import c.universe._; /* other code */ }`

Answer (score 2):

> whats the reason to mandate specifying a universe before using Scala reflection?

Because macros in Scala are context dependent and the universe import for each macro passes in the context.